# Documentation to understand mm part of Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I was wondering if there is any good documentation available to understand memory management part Linux kernel. I have already gone thorough memory management part of "Linux kernel development" book.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the code? There is no magic formula to understand Linux except to read it. Most books tend to quickly become outdated and are only useful for historical or overview purposes.

Comment: @user3427419: I'm a newbie, I have no idea where should I start? The goal of my life is to understand mm part of source.

Comment: Start reading. It's not that long. `sloccount` of mm tree is only 66k lines of code, most very well commented and generally excellently written. It references other parts too, but I'm assuming you know now about spin locks and the like. Since the goal of your life is to understand only that much, then you should have no problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kernel books go, "Linux Kernel Development" is one of the most "friendly" and easy to understand for those new to kernel development, but it has very little detail. I would recommend "Professional Linux Kernel Architecture" by Wolfgang Mauerer: it is *far* more detailed than LKD, and while it is getting a bit old, most of the information still applies.

O'Reilly also has a book called "Understanding the Linux Kernel", but it is quite out-of-date. It does not contain as much information as PLKA, and I also found it less readable.

There is also a free book available for download called "Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager". It is older than all the books mentioned above. I've never read it, so I can't comment on it.

Whichever book you use, keep a copy of the source code close at hand and refer to it frequently!

Comment: So far, I have found "Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager" very useful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Memory Management(mm) is the most complex and important part of Linux Kernel. It nearly runs though the entire Kernel, no matter process management or filesystem. So, if you just want to know how `mm` works without the knowledges of other parts, I think it is unpractical.

The shortest way to understand the mechanism behind memory management is to read the relevant chapters of Linux Kernel books, such as [*Linux Kernel Development*](http://reiber.org/nxt/pub/Linux/LinuxKernelDevelopment/Linux.Kernel.Development.3rd.Edition.pdf) or [*Understanding the Linux Kernel*](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c4022/code/memory/understanding.pdf) which are mentioned by Alex D above.

If you wish to be an expert of Linux Kernel, however, nothing will be better than reading source codes. Reading source codes is actually boring and painful, but it will help you to go deep into the core of system.

Sometimes, before you start the joinery of reading kernel source, developing linux driver module is a good start point.

BTW:Some web sites or subscriptions can give you lots of useful informations, such as http://lxr.free-electrons.com/, http://kernelnewbies.org/ or http://lwn.net/.

Subscribe LKML(Linux Kernel Mail List) is another way to get the newest info about where kernel will go.